# Total Probability - Tickets

Tags: probability

I am looking to calculate the total probability of my chances to win a prize from 3 raffles I have entered.

Raffle 1 the probability of me winning is 0.34. 
The probability of me winning raffle  2 is 0.27.
Finally, the probability of me winning raffle 3 is 0.27 also.

How would I go about calculating the total probability that I will win out of these 3 raffles?

P.S I am new to the concept of the law of total probability, hence finding it quite difficult to wrap my head around.

Comment: Presumably each raffle is run independently of one another and you are asking for the probability that you win at least one of the raffles.  Letting $A,B,C$ represent winning the first, second, and third raffles respectively, you can calculate $Pr(A\cup B\cup C)=1-Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C^c) = 1-Pr(A^c)Pr(B^c)Pr(C^c)$.  I.e. winning at least one is the opposite event of winning zero, hence the first equals sign.  Breaking apart the probability of the intersections as the product of the probabilities follows from the independence assumption and gives the second equals sign.

Comment: You want probability of win-lose-lose + lose-win-lose + lose-lose-win

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon that would be for winning exactly one of the raffles, not at least one of the raffles.  Granted, the OP didn't do a very good job of specifying exactly what he is looking for, but from context I would expect he wants at least one win instead of exactly one.

Comment: Apologies for the poor specification, I am just going off from what has been provided in a practise sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of winning prize = 1 - probability of not winning any raffle
$ = 1 - (1-0.34)(1-0.27)^2 = 1 - 0.66\cdot (0.73)^2$

Comment: My final answer for this sum is therefore 0.58. Is this correct? I feel that a probability of 0.58 is very high considering the nature of the other probabilities from the single raffles.

Comment: No it is 0.648286 I guess

Comment: would I then deduct the 0.648286 from 1 to obtain a final probability? Asking this as a probability of 0.64.. still feels extremely high

Comment: What does from 1 means?

Comment: Would my final answer for the probability of all the raffles = 1 - 0.648286?

Comment: No its 0.649286 only

Comment: You have 3 raffles so probability of winning becomes high

Comment: Dude only raffle one have probability 0.34 to win and there are two more raffles having some probability which will increase the probability of winning. So its high.

Comment: brilliant thanks for the assistance.